# How can I make the signature of this function more precise

Tags: haskell, types

I have two functions:

```
prompt :: Text -> (Text -> Either Text a) -> IO a
subPrompt :: Text -> (Text -> Bool) -> IO a -> IO (Maybe (Text, a))
```

subPrompt takes a second prompt (argument 3) and displays it if the function in argument 2 comes back as true after running the first prompt.

What I don't like is that argument 3 is `IO a` I would like it to be something more like:

```
subPrompt :: Text -> (Text -> Bool) -> prompt -> IO (Maybe (Text, a))
```

But I know I can't do that. I'm stuck trying to think of a way to make it clearer from the signature what the third argument is. Is there some way I can define a clearer type? Or maybe I'm overthinking it and `IO a` is actually fine - I'm pretty new to haskell.

Comment: What are some examples of non-`IO`y things you would want to be able to pass there? What should `subPrompt` do with them?

Comment: Oh, no, it is always IO. I guess I am asking if there is a way I can make it a specific sort of IO.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand: you want to ensure that the third argument to `subPrompt` is actually a call to `prompt` (and not, say, `deleteDirectory "/"`), right? I have written an answer about one approach, but while writing it I pondered: would you also want to allow passing the result of `subPrompt` as a third argument to `subPrompt`? (In my answer I assumed "yes", but it is certainly possible to adapt to the "no" situation, too.)

Comment: You thought correctly :) I want to be able to have an arbitrary number of subPrompts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with making the second prompt a simple `IO a` - specially if you document what it is somewhere.

That said, yes, it is good practice to make the types as self-explanatory as possible; you can create an alias:

```hs
type Prompt a = IO a
```

and then use it in subPrompt's signature:

```hs
subPrompt :: Text -> (Text -> Bool) -> Prompt a -> IO (Maybe (Text, a))
```

This makes the signature more self-explanatory, while still allowing you to pass any `IO a` as the third parameter (the keyword `type` just creates an alias).

But wait, there is more: you'd rather not accidentally pass any `IO a` that isn't actually a prompt! You don't want to pass it an IO action that, say, launches the missiles...

So, we can declare an actual Prompt type (not just an alias, but a real type):

```hs
newtype Prompt a = Prompt { getPrompt :: IO a }
```

This allows you to wrap any value of type `IO a` inside a type, ensuring it doesn't get mixed up with other functions with the same type, but different semantics.

The signature of subPrompt remains the same as before:

```hs
subPrompt :: Text -> (Text -> Bool) -> Prompt a -> IO (Maybe (Text, a))
```

But now you cannot pass just any old `IO a` to it; to pass your `prompt`, for example, you have to wrap it:

```hs
subPrompt "Do we proceed?" askYesNo (Prompt (prompt "Please enter your name" processName))
```

(subPrompt won't be able to call it directly, but will have to extract "prompt" from inside the wrapper:  `let actualPrompt = getPrompt wrappedPrompt`)

Comment: Ah, newtype is exactly what I need. I previously struggled with the difference between type and newtype. But this makes it crystal clear - it stops the accidental case, as you said. Thanks!

Comment: This answer would be much better if it changed the types of `prompt` (and `subPrompt`?) to return `Prompt`s instead of `IO`s and discussed how to use module boundaries to make sure that users can't accidentally turn arbitrary `IO` actions into `Prompt`s.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to reify the two things as a data structure. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Prompt a where
    Prompt :: Text -> (Text -> Either Text a) -> Prompt a
    SubPrompt :: Text -> (Text -> Bool) -> Prompt a -> Prompt (Maybe (Text, a))
```

Now because the third argument to `SubPrompt` is a `Prompt`, you know it must either be a call to `SubPrompt` or `Prompt` -- definitely not some arbitrary `IO` action that might do filesystem access or some other nasty thing.

Then you can write an interpreter for this tiny DSL into `IO`:

```
runPrompt :: Prompt a -> IO a
runPrompt (Prompt cue validator) = {- what your old prompt used to do -}
runPrompt (SubPrompt cue deeper sub) = {- what your old subPrompt used to do,
                                          calling runPrompt on sub where needed -}
```

Besides the benefit of being sure you don't have arbitrary `IO` as an argument to `SubPrompt`, this has the side benefit that it makes testing easier. Later you could implement a second interpreter that is completely pure; say, something like this, which takes a list of texts to be treated as user inputs and returns a list of texts that the prompt output:

```
data PromptResult a = Done a | NeedsMoreInput (Prompt a)

purePrompt :: Prompt a -> [Text] -> ([Text], PromptResult a)
purePrompt = {- ... -}
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. My project is already using the previous style though, which is why I accepted typedfern's answer. But I'll strongly consider refactoring to this style in the future. Thanks!